# `Syntax error: "(" unexpected` when creating an array

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I have two (Debian) Linux servers. I am creating a shell script.

On the first one I create an array thus:

```
#!/bin/bash
target_array=(
    "/home/user/direct/filename -p123 -r"
)
```

That works fine. But when I run this on the other server I get:

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

As far as I can tell both servers are the same. Can anyone shed some light on why this doesn't work?

If I type it into the terminal directly it is fine??

---

It would appear that when I run it as

```
sh scriptname.sh
```

I get the error, but if I run it as

```
./scriptname.sh
```

it seems to be ok. What's the difference?

Comment: Did you copy-pasted the script between the two server? try `cat -v <script>` to see if there are spurious char.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

When you use `./scriptname.sh` it executes with `/bin/bash` as in the first line with `#!`. But when you use `sh scriptname.sh` it executes `sh`, not `bash`.

The `sh` shell has no syntax to create arrays, but Bash has the syntax you used.

Comment: The sh language has no arrays (`a[index]=x` or `a=(x y)`). Some sh interpreters support arrays, only ksh88 (not ported to Linux AFAIK) and some older pdksh variants would support `a[index]=value` and not `a=(x y)`. On Debian, `sh` is usually `dash` which has no array support (`a[index]=x` won't work).

Answer (score 2):

Running `./scriptname.sh` will result in reading the first line of the file and see that it needs to run ´/bin/bash´ and pass the rest of the script to the interpreter, while executing `sh scriptname.sh` will pass the file to the user's standard shell (e.g. Ash) and be the case that that other interpreter does not support arrays as Bash does.

Comment: `sh` is not necessarily the "user's standard shell" it's often its own executable (or symlink) and `sh` will be invoked to process the script.  That will be true if even if the default login shell for that user is `bash`

Comment: That was the part in which I was not entirely sure at the moment. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

With `sh scriptname.sh`, you are running it with `sh`, not necessarily with `bash`. Try comparing `sh --version` on both machines. And/or with `dpkg -S $(which sh)`.

Comment: Even if `sh` is a symlink to `bash` it will behave differently when invoked as `sh`